# parse image from json but can not display in listview

Tags: android, json

i have json which contains image url and
i follow [this](http://www.wingnity.com/blog/android-json-parsing-and-image-loading-tutorial/) tutorial ,i download source code,works fine, but when i implement same thing in my application it displays my listview is empty
when i'm debug the code i getting know ,the adapter which has to fill the list view is load the data ,but listview cant
this is my activity

```
public class ListNotificationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 Toolbar toolbar;

private ProgressDialog pDialog;

private static String url = "http://staging.talentslist.com/api/user/24/notification";
ArrayList<NotificationData> notiList;
ListView listview;
NotificAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_notification);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.notification));
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    notiList = new ArrayList<NotificationData>();
    new GetList().execute(url);

    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.notificationList);

    adapter = new NotificAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_item, notiList);

    listview.setAdapter(adapter);


}

private class GetList extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ListNotificationActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading, please wait");
        pDialog.setTitle("Connecting server");
        pDialog.show();
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
        HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
        URL urlObj = null;
        try {
            urlObj = new URL(urls[0]);


            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();
            InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();


            // StatusLine stat = response.getStatusLine();
            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            //    int status = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

            if (status == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
                JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("data");

                for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    NotificationData notidata = new NotificationData();

                    notidata.setId(object.getInt("id"));
                    notidata.setUser_name(object.getString("user_name"));
                    notidata.setTitle(object.getString("title"));
                    notidata.setIs_read(object.getString("is_read"));
                    notidata.setCreated_at(object.getString("created_at"));
                    notidata.setImage_link(object.getString("image_link"));
                    notiList.add(notidata);
                }
                return true;


            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        pDialog.cancel();

       adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        if (result == false)
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to fetch data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

}

this is my adapter class

```
public class NotificAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<NotificationData> {

ArrayList<NotificationData> nDataAdapter;
LayoutInflater vi;
int Resource;
ViewHolder holder;

public NotificAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<NotificationData> objects) {
    super(context, resource);
    vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    Resource = resource;
    nDataAdapter = objects;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        v = vi.inflate(Resource, null);
        holder.imageview = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
        holder.tvSender_name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.sender_name);
        holder.tvNoti_details = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.noti_details);
        holder.tvDate = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.date);
        v.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }

    holder.imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.noimage);
    new DownloadImageTask(holder.imageview).execute(nDataAdapter.get(position).getImage_link());
    holder.tvSender_name.setText(nDataAdapter.get(position).getUser_name());
    holder.tvNoti_details.setText(nDataAdapter.get(position).getUser_name());
    holder.tvDate.setText(nDataAdapter.get(position).getCreated_at());

    return v;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    public ImageView imageview;
    public TextView tvSender_name;
    public TextView tvNoti_details;
    public TextView tvDate;
}

private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

}
this is list item layout for listview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="5dip" >

<!--  ListRow Left sied Thumbnail image -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
    android:background="@drawable/image_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="3dip">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/list_image"
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:src="@drawable/noimage" />

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sender_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:text="Notification from"
    android:textColor="#040404"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:textSize="15dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/noti_details"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:text="Notification details"
    android:textColor="#343434"
    android:textSize="10dip" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/name"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:text="Time"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
    android:textSize="10dip"
    android:textColor="#10bcc9"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

please help me!!

Comment: http://androidcss.com/android/fetch-json-data-android/

Comment: That's how end following random tutorials from author who is live in the place where everyone are experts in android's development ... Obviosuly this is bad tutorial and bad AsyncTask usage

Comment: Can you just comment this line in adapter  `new DownloadImageTask(holder.imageview).execute(nDataAdapter.get(position).getImage_link()); ?`

Answer (score 0):

make some changes when you getting data to add all data into list.
and make separate method for set adapter like below ..

```
    /**
 * this method used set adapter into list view.
 */
private void setAdapter(){
    if (adapter==null) {
        adapter = new NotificAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_item, notiList);

        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } 
    else{
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
}
```

then after above method call in this block in your code ..

```
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    setAdapter();
    if (result == false)
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to fetch data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

Comment: check after comment this  line new DownloadImageTask(holder.imageview).execute(nDataAdapter.get(position).getImage_link());